# Spring MVC and JSON, Jackson class not found exception

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

I cant get Spring's JSON support working. In my spring-servlet.xml file i have included following lines:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="my.packagename.here" />
<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
```

I have also downloaded jackson libraries and added them to my eclipse project and also to WEB-INF/lib folder. When sending request to controller with jQuery getJSON method i get following errors:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonProcessingException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException
```

What do you think is the problem. I'm guessing it has something to do with my `spring-servlet.xml` file. I can paste entire error log, if you need.

Comment: which jackson jars have you added?

Comment: I have a same problem with Jackson v2.0.1 jars. All the jars (core, annotation, databind) in place. Did you resolve this issue by any chance?

Comment: So is this a mismatch between jackson 1.x and 2.x?  I notice that the class complained about is org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException.  I open my jar file and the path is completely different to the JsonProcessingException, that is org.springframework...<etc>...JsonProcessingException

Comment: I faced the same problem and resolved problem by changing spring 3 into 4 and added org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JsonProcessingException is part of the jackson-core-asl-x.x.x.jar. Make sure that it's part of your classpath.

Comment: Well I can see it sitting right there in jackson-core package, still getting the exception

Answer (score 43):

For Jackson v2 jars, class to be used for bean should be

```
<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
```

For older jackson version, org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter is ok. Make sure the jar files are added to the project library.

Answer (score 10):

The answer of anshul tiwari partially captures the problem.  Here is a more complete answer ...

When Jackson made it to version 2.0, the core library got changed from jackson-core-asl-x.x.x.jar to jackson-core-x.x.x.jar.  With that, the paths changed.  In version 1, org.codehaus.jackson was the path.  In version 2, it is in com.fasterxml.jackson.core if you were to open up the jar file.

Now if you have the libraries of version 2 and you are seeing the org.codehaus.jackson ClassNotFoundException, it means that there is a mixing of versions.  Some code is expecting v1 but you have provided v2.  This is certainly possible when using Spring so you have to be careful to choose the correct jar file for your code.

**EDIT**

In fact, looking at 3.2 Spring source code, `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` still references the org.codehaus stuff so this is a case where Spring source code needs to import the correct path and there is nothing you the developer can do to use jackson 2.

Comment: This answer just ended 6 hours of bashing my head against a brick wall.  If I could +10 I would.  The latest version of spring (4.1) uses jackson 2.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement anshul tiwari answer, the bean tag should go inside mvc:annotation-driver:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter" />
        <!-- <bean -->
        <!-- class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter" 
            /> -->
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
        <!-- <bean -->
        <!-- class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" 
            /> -->
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it Like below : Hope it will work..

http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="true">

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.vc.bmp.resource" />
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <!-- property name="prefixJson" value="true" />
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" /-->
            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper">
                    <property name="serializationInclusion">
                        <value type="com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include">NON_NULL</value>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```